# Initial Item in Data bound Combobox is not selected. Even though the Bound Object has a Value

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a class which is creating a Combobox with a Databinding to an Object.
The Object has a Value for an enum. But when the ComboBox is loaded it doesnt Contain a Value. The Following is the part where i´m creating the ComboBox.[image]

```
ComboBox combBox = new ComboBox();
        combBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        combBox.BackColor = Color.White;
        combBox.DisplayMember = "Anzeige";
        combBox.ValueMember = "Value";

        var values = Enum.GetValues(EnumType);

        foreach(int value in values)
        {
            ComboBoxItemClass comboBoxItemClass = new ComboBoxItemClass() { Value = value, Anzeige = Enum.GetName(EnumType, value) };
            combBox.Items.Add(comboBoxItemClass);
        }

        combBox.DataBindings.Add(nameof(combBox.SelectedValue), NAFDetailView.CurrentObject, PropertyName, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem by getting rid of the ComboBoxItemClass, and assigning the DataSource of the ComboBox, after that i used the SelectedItem Property for the DataBinding as follows.

```
ComboBox combBox = new ComboBox();
combBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
combBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(EnumType);
combBox.DataBindings.Add(nameof(combBox.SelectedItem), NAFDetailView.CurrentObject, PropertyName, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    combBox.SelectedText = "Anzeige";
```

i am using this code for displaying text on load.

Comment: The Problem is that i want to show the Enumname of the Object to which the Box is bound to.

Comment: yourComboBox.DataSource =  Enum.GetValues(typeof(YourEnum));

YourEnum enum = (YourEnum) yourComboBox.SelectedItem;

yourComboBox.SelectedItem = YourEnum.Foo;

Comment: I don´t have a specific Type, the enum behind the ComboBox is variable, the initial Value also variable